# Initialize state variables vs constructor

Tags: solidity, constructor, state-variable

What is the purpose of Constructor if I can initialize the state variables directly.

```
contract ConZ {
    address public owner = msg.sender;
    uint public x = 123;
}
```

_

```
contract Conx {
    address public owner;
    uint public;

   constructor(uint _x) {
     owner = msg.sender;
     x = _x;
   }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You can‘t initialise everything like that. And sometimes you need to call another contract in the deployment and u musst do that inside the constructor

Answer (score 1):

The constructor can do much more than initialize state variables, it can run code, deploy other contracts... Plus in some cases you'll want to deploy a contract multiple times with different state variables, in this case it's way more convenient to have a constructor that takes those variable as inputs than having to change your source code everytime (which is sometimes impossible, for example when your contract is deployed by another contract)